# find all $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathrm{e}^{4\omega} + 5\mathrm{e}^{2\omega} + 6 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I'm taking a beginners course in complex analysis and
I need to find all values for $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathrm{e}^{4\omega} + 5\mathrm{e}^{2\omega} + 6 = 0$

I tried doing it with the $\ln$ but I just got some really weird stuff.

Comment: Put $z=e^{2w}$. Solve the quadratic $z^{2}+5z+6=0$.

Comment: so now I get 2 = ^2 and 3 = ^2 is that correct? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @selmar yes and now you can take ln on both sides to get the values of $\omega$